# zlib1g dev not installing properly. Help installing?

Tags: zlib

I have been having issues with installing zlib1g-dev (I need it for rbenv to work). Apt will not install it, saying that I don't have the required dependencies (it doesn't say exactly which zlib1g i need, but I have the "2ubuntu4" version. I manually downloaded the package from the Ubuntu repos, however when I open it with Ubuntu Software it still does not install.

Error logs:

```
foo@foo:/$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
[sudo] password for foo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you tried an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Yeah. Several times.

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install zlib1g` to update the held dependency?

Comment: @ScottSwezey Yes. It says that I have the newest version.

Comment: Instead of playing 20 questions asking whether you've tried something or not, it would be much better if you [edit] your post and include the things you've already tried and the results of those efforts there instead. Burying details in comments isn't helpful, and neither is having to pry the information out of you. You're asking us for help solving your problem; it's in your best interest to give us the details you already have, and that includes what you've already done to try to solve the problem.